# Открывать добавленное видео в WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Работая над проектом столкнулся с задачей - **Открывать добавленное видео в WebView**.

Найдя замечательный образец, решил разобраться на его примере.

Суть проекта:

1. Пользователь добавляет скопированную ссылку(с youtube/vimeo) в наше приложение(нажав кнопку ADD)
2. После того как пользователь нажал "ADD" мы в нашем RecyclerView получаем превью нашего видео.

Ну и собственно ***задача***, после того, как мы добавили превью нашего видео, добавить возможность по нажатию на элемент списка(в данном случае это наше видео) открывать его по нажатию путём WebView(в браузере) или же в самом приложении.

Дополнительно:
Нашёл способ как открывать видео красиво в новой активити, но увы не знаю как использовать к ссылкам, которые будут добавляться каждый раз по разному. Именно поэтому если правильно понимаю, нужно сохранять ссылки которые вводит пользователь - *догадка*.

```
String frameVideo = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"415\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Ну и собственно рабочий код самой программы:
Адаптер для RecyclerView

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;
private Context mContext;

public DataAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_video_preview, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.mPreviewLinkTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getVideoLink());
    viewHolder.mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink()).resize(120, 90).into(viewHolder.mPreviewImageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public void addItem(VideoPreview videoPreview) {
    mItems.add(videoPreview);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public boolean contains(VideoPreview newVideoPreview) {
    for (VideoPreview videoPreview : mItems) {
        if (videoPreview.getVideoLink().equals(newVideoPreview.getVideoLink()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView mPreviewImageView;
    TextView mPreviewLinkTextView;
    TextView mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mPreviewImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_image_view);
        mPreviewLinkTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_text_view);
        mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_preview_text_view);
    }
}
}
```

Код Acitivity

```
public class VideoPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoTypes {

private RecyclerView mVideoPreviewRecyclerView;
private EditText mAddEditText;
private Button mAddButton;

private OkHttpClient httpClient;
private DataAdapter mDataAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);

    mVideoPreviewRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview_recycler_view);
    mAddEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_edit_text);
    mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

    mVideoPreviewRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.video_preview_recycler_view);
    mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mDataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);

    httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mDataAdapter.getItemCount() == 10) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not add more than 10 videos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String videoLink = mAddEditText.getText().toString();
            int videoType = VideoMethods.getLinkType(videoLink);

            if (videoType == TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect link!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mAddEditText.getText().clear();

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) VideoPreviewActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(VideoPreviewActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            String videoId = VideoMethods.getId(videoLink);

            switch (videoType) {
                case TYPE_YOUTUBE:
                    VideoPreview videoPreview = new VideoPreview(videoLink, "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/1.jpg");
                    if (!mDataAdapter.contains(videoPreview)) {
                        mDataAdapter.addItem(videoPreview);
                        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This video already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    break;

                case TYPE_VIMEO:
                    try {
                        getVimeoPreview(videoLink, videoId);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something going wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void getVimeoPreview(final String videoLink, final String videoId) throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + videoId + ".xml")
            .build();

    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something going wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            String s = response.body().string();

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<thumbnail_small>(.*)<\\/thumbnail_small>");
            final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            m.find();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    VideoPreview videoPreview = new VideoPreview(videoLink, m.group(1));
                    if (!mDataAdapter.contains(videoPreview)) {
                        mDataAdapter.addItem(videoPreview);
                        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This video already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Возможно будет также полезен класс `VideoMethods` для обработки ссылок на видео:

```
public static int getLinkType(String link) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https:\\/\\/www\\.(youtube\\.com)\\/watch\\?v=[\\w-]{11}$|^https:\\/\\/(youtu\\.be)\\/[\\w-]{11}$|^https:\\/\\/(vimeo\\.com)\\/[0-9]*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
    if (!matcher.matches())
        return TYPE_UNKNOWN;

    for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return TYPE_YOUTUBE;
                case 3:
                    return TYPE_VIMEO;
                default:
                    return TYPE_UNKNOWN;
            }
        }
    }
    return TYPE_UNKNOWN;
}

public static String getId(String link) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v=([\\w-]{11})$|^https:\\/\\/youtu\\.be\\/([\\w-]{11})$|^https:\\/\\/vimeo\\.com\\/([0-9]*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
    matcher.matches();

    for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
            return matcher.group(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что значит «проверить нажатие на элемент (содержащий в ссылку)»?

Comment: ну я кликую по элементу в списке
а этот  элемент содержит в себе ссылку.

Comment: Хм, где-то я это уже видел и рассказывал. Ну, без кода адаптера для «списка»  Вам что-то конкретное вряд ли подскажут.

Comment: Да, это я еще в поисках решения, по Вашим советам, но уже другому пути)
Пробую по разному.

Comment: Берешь span, стилизируешь его под ссылку, вешаешь на click обработчик и там проверяешь все что хочешь.

Comment: Сложность-то в чем? Вы можете сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка появлялось уведомление, в котором бы отображалась **ссылка на видео, на которое нажал пользователь**? В этом проблема?

Comment: @post_zeew задача еще проще как мне кажется, но не могу докодить норм) просто нажимаю на превью видео которое добавил в список и оно открывается в webview.

Comment: @Inkognito, Вы можете сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка появлялось уведомление, в котором бы отображалась ссылка на видео, на которое нажал пользователь? Иными словами: Вы можете определить ссылку на видео, по которому нажал пользователь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> но увы не знаю как использовать к ссылкам, которые будут добавляться каждый раз по разному. Именно поэтому если правильно понимаю, нужно сохранять ссылки которые вводит пользователь

При добавлении элементов в список, эти элементы добавляются в `mItems` адаптера, то есть ссылки на видео будут автоматически сохранены.

### Проигрывать видео в `WebView` – затея весьма нехорошая

Но если Вы уж так хотите...

Адаптер:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public DataAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_video_preview, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.mPreviewLinkTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getVideoLink());
        viewHolder.mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink()).resize(120, 90).into(viewHolder.mPreviewImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public void addItem(VideoPreview videoPreview) {
        mItems.add(videoPreview);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean contains(VideoPreview newVideoPreview) {
        for (VideoPreview videoPreview : mItems) {
            if (videoPreview.getVideoLink().equals(newVideoPreview.getVideoLink()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView mPreviewImageView;
        TextView mPreviewLinkTextView;
        TextView mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, VideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("video_link", mItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).getVideoLink());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            mPreviewImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_image_view);
            mPreviewLinkTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_text_view);
            mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_preview_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_video.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/video_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`VideoActivity`:

```
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video_web_view);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String videoLink = extras.getString("video_link");

            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            });
            
            mWebView.loadUrl(videoLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ, но почему затея не очень хорошая? Потому как именно к этому варианту я пришёл искав решение на просторах интернета. Как бы посоветовали Вы воспроизводить видео(вариант с установкой mediaplayer не актуален для меня)?

Comment: + в RecyclerView вы обращаетесь к ссылке через getAdapterPosition, а каков аналог в gridView?

Comment: как обращаться в gridView разобрался, но там как понимаю элементы не добавляются в items адаптера. Поэтому ссылки нужно как то все же сохранять. Не подскажете каким образом это возможно?

Comment: @Inkognito, Потому что в 9 из 10 случаях видео воспроизводиться не будет. Я бы посоветовал использовать API соответствующих видео-хостингов.

Comment: «Поэтому ссылки нужно как то все же сохранять. Не подскажете каким образом это возможно?» – например таким, каким это реализовано здесь.

Comment: в методе onClick? там где mItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).getVideoLink()); ?

Comment: Нет, при добавлении в адаптер.

Comment: в методе addItem?

Comment: @Inkognito, Откуда же я знаю, каким образом Вы добавляете данные? Если с помощью `addItem(...)`, то да, там.

Comment: "например таким, каким это реализовано здесь" извините, но я здесь не совсем понимаю где в Вашем примере ссылки сохраняются.

Comment: @Inkognito, Ссылка находится в объекте класса `VideoPreview`, при добавлении элемента в список, мы добавляем соответствующий объект в `ArrayList` адаптера.