# Коллекции с моделями и мои проблемы с ними

Tags: java, android, коллекции

Разбираюсь с этими коллекциями, по-прежнему что то делаю не так.

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("position", position);
                            images.add(imageUploads.get(position).getUrl().toString());
                            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", new ArrayList<String>());
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

По нажатию на фото(у меня они идут целым списком), создаётся типа коллекция, дальше идёт работа с интентом и `FullScreenViewActivity.class` , после чего я ПРОБУЮ добавлять из модели по позиции ССЫЛКУ этой фотографии.
После чего `putStringArrayListExtra` заношу опять же в коллекцию.

Класс `FullScreenViewActivity`

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<String> photo = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    int position = 0;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i != null) {
        position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        photo.addAll(getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("items_to_parse"));
    }
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    int width = size.x;

    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, photo,width);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}
```

Пытаюсь внести изменения только в `onClick` т.к. данная активити работает корректно(но для других активити).
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так в этом  `onClick'e`.

Comment: Вы помещаете пустой список строк в интент

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как мне его можно заполнить значениями, которые вводит пользователь. А именно ссылками хотелось бы(есть модель , где есть getUrl() - но он без параметров) - тут тоже незадача, затрудняюсь задать значения параметру.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, Вы хотите передать `images`, а передаете пустой (другой, вновь созданный) список.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, у вас есть список моделей, а вам надо передать в другую активити список из значений одного из полей модели. Для этого можно пробежаться циклом по моделям и сформировать список строк так:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for(ImageUpload imageUpload: imageUploads)
{
    strings.add(imageUpload.getUrl().toString());
}
```

Теперь передавайте полученный список строк в Intent

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items_to_parse", (ArrayList)strings);
```

Comment: спасибо за реакцию, только вот я добавил к примеру ссылки, но для начало мне нужно их по идее проSet'ить чтобы открыть их потом, если понадобится?

Comment: так понял сначала SET потом ADD?
иначе я не смогу добавить значения(ссылки) картинок.

Comment: @Inkognito, Метод `add(...)` добавляет объект в список, метод `set(...)` устанавливает объект в списке по позиции. Использовать **оба** метода для одного и того же объекта **бессмысленно**.

Comment: @post_zeew хорошо, добавили мы объект(ссылку) в список, а куда именно мы же не знаем. Именно поэтому нужно сперва установить данный объект(ссылку) для конкретного элемента(то есть по позиции).

Comment: @Inkognito, Метод `add(E element)` добавляет объект в конец списка. Если Вы хотите добавить объект в определенной позицию, то можно воспользоваться методом `add(int index, E element)`. Я, правда, так и не понял, зачем знать в какую именно позицию добавлен элемент.

Comment: @post_zeew до сих пор пытаюсь решить данную задачу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581918/220675 только для своего приложения.